# How to adjust the vertical spacing before and after section headings to be symmetrical in KOMA-Script classes?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script, vertical-spacing, section-titles

Here is my MWE compiled using `LuaLaTeX`:

[image: MWE]

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt, DIV=12, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

    % Replace \autodot with "." for \section headings
\xpretocmd{\sectionformat}{\def\autodot{.}}{}{\cfPatchFailed} 
    % Section heading font settings
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{section}{\Large}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\large}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize}

    % Spacing of section headings
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    beforeskip=-0.25\baselineskip,
    afterskip=0.25\baselineskip
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    beforeskip=-0.25\baselineskip,
    afterskip=0.25\baselineskip
]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    beforeskip=-0.25\baselineskip,
    afterskip=0.25\baselineskip
]{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1][1-5]
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

I want the vertical spacing before and after `\section`s, `\subsection`s, and `\subsubsection`s respectively to be symmetrical (hence I've set `beforeskip` and `afterskip` to be equal) but I do not know how to achieve this because upon closer inspection the spacing seems to be asymmetrical. (For clarity, I've highlighted the text in Acrobat.)

[image: Highlighted MWE 1]

[image: Highglighted MWE 2]

So my questions are

#### Why is the vertical spacing before and after the section headings asymmetrical even when `beforeskip` and `afterskip` are equal?

#### How can I adjust the vertical spacing before and after section headings to be symmetrical in KOMA-Script classes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\baselineskip` depends on the the font size. So if you are using a larger font for sections than for subsection, the space after section is larger than than the space after subsection and subsection immediately follows a section, the space between section and subsection is the (larger) space after the section, not the space before the subsection. So if you want the same spaces everywhere you have to use an absolute value like 5pt:

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt, DIV=12, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

    % Replace \autodot with "." for \section headings
\xpretocmd{\sectionformat}{\def\autodot{.}}{}{\cfPatchFailed} 
    % Section heading font settings
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\linespread{1}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{section}{\Large}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\large}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize}

    % Spacing of section headings
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    beforeskip=-5pt,
    afterskip=5pt
]{section,subsection,subsubsection}

% Following just makes the headings lines visible for debugging
\xpretocmd{\sectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{yellow}\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\linewidth}{\baselineskip}}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\subsectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{yellow}\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\linewidth}{\baselineskip}}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\subsubsectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{yellow}\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\linewidth}{\baselineskip}}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{yellow}\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\linewidth}{\baselineskip}}%
\lipsum[1][1-5]
\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{yellow}\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\linewidth}{\baselineskip}}%
Last line of the paragraph.

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've added some yellow backgrounds to visualize the line height and depth of normal text and headings.